# Android ListView RSS Reader on a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, rss, android-adapter

So.
I'm pretty noob in fragments, and i spent my last days tryin to show a very very simple RSS Reader in an app which has many fragments. 
I was following a guide (actually many guides, but this one was the one which had less code.. just for learning purpose: http://www.html.it/pag/19519/android-e-le-applicazioni-di-rete/).

This is the xml about the fragment in which i would to show the RSS Reader (called fragment_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#607D8B"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:id="@+id/main1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/newsBanner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/news_banner"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="News:"
    android:id="@+id/newsTitleText1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollerNews1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newsTitleText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rssListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Yeah it has "main1" id because is the "default" layout fragment at the opening of the app.
And this is the java class

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

String feedUrl = "";
ListView rssListView = null;
ArrayList<RSSItem> RSSItems = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> array_adapter = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View setView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    feedUrl = "sample_feed_url";

    refreshRSSList();

    rssListView = (ListView) setView.findViewById(R.id.rssListView);

    array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_main, RSSItems);
    rssListView.setAdapter(array_adapter);

    refreshRSSList();

    return setView;

}

private void refreshRSSList() {

    ArrayList<RSSItem> newItems = RSSItem.getRSSItems(feedUrl);
    RSSItems.clear();
    RSSItems.addAll(newItems);

}
```

At the moment when i run the app, everything is showed except for the listview (which, i guess, is empty).

Many thanks to whoever will help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your array adapter, the layout parameter is wrong. You have mentioned the layout of the fragment. Here it's asking the layout of listview. I mean layout of an item in listview. You need to create a new file in layout and name it as list_item.xml. Define list_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item_textview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical">
</TextView>
```

Now your array adapter will be

```
array_adapter =new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,R.id.list_item_textview,rssItems);
```

You can also use the constructor which you have defined. What I did explicitly mentions id of TextView. You can see the difference here: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)). Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: First, thank you so much for your answer. I see what i got wrong, so I did as you said. But the rss still isn't visible :S
Could it be an issue in RSSItem class?

Comment: Oh I didn't see the RSSItem class. It needs to be simple string. If you want to show different items in a single listview item, you have a make a custom adapter. In the documentation, it says it is for simple textView.

Comment: Just gave a try to the constructor which explicitly mentions the id of TextView. Nothing changed. I also checked RSSItem class and everything seems fine (and yes, it's a simple String as i need to show in the rss reader). I even tried to change the rss feed with no different results.

Comment: Ok I tried to manually add items to the ArrayList RSSItems and it works. RSS reader still have troubles in populating by himself. But it  i guess is a problem concerning the RSSItem class. So thank you for your help. For what you could do, you have been so useful!